# Snake game C code is not working for bigger length and height values

Tags: c

I am writing code for snake game using C programming language. In my code, when I am trying to take bigger length and height value for game border then output is somehow got distorted. Please let me know how can I make border which could cover whole console window and what is the issue with existing code.

My code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAXTL 100
int len=20,wid=20;
int headX,headY,fruitX,fruitY,gameOver,level,flag=0,score=0;
int tailX[MAXTL];int tailY[MAXTL];
int countTail=0;
void draw();
void defaultsetting();
void userinput();
void my_sleep(int level);
//void delay();

void draw(){
    system("cls");

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<wid;j++){
            if(i==0 || i==len-1){
                printf("=");
            }
            else if(j==0 || j==wid-1){
                printf("#");
            }
            else{
                    if(i==headX && j==headY){
                      printf("O");
                    }
                    else if(i==fruitX && j==fruitY){
                      printf("*");
                    }
                    else{
                            int tail=0;
                        for(int k=0;k<countTail;k++){
                            if(i==tailX[k]&& j==tailY[k]){
                                printf("-");
                                tail=1;
                            }
                        }
                        if(tail==0){
                            printf(" ");
                        }

                    }

            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



}
void defaultsetting(){
    gameOver=0;
    srand(time(0));
    headX=len/2;
    headY=wid/2;
do{
    fruitX=rand()%20;
    fruitY=rand()%20;
}while(fruitX==0||fruitY==0);
}
void userinput(){
    if(kbhit()){
        switch(getch()){
        case 72://up
            flag=1;
            break;

        case 75://left
            flag=2;
            break;

        case 77://right
            flag=3;
            break;

        case 80://down
            flag=4;
            break;

        case 'q':
            gameOver=1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void logic(){
    srand(time(0));
    int i,prev2X,prev2Y;
    int prevX=tailX[0];
    int prevY=tailY[0];
    tailX[0]=headX;
    tailY[0]=headY;
    for(i=1;i<countTail;i++){
        prev2X=tailX[i];
        prev2Y=tailY[i];
        tailX[i]=prevX;
        tailY[i]=prevY;
        prevX=prev2X;
        prevY=prev2Y;
    }
    switch(flag){
        case 1:
            headX--;
            break;
        case 2:
            headY--;
            break;
        case 3:
            headY++;
            break;
        case 4:
            headX++;
            break;
        default:
            //printf("Inside default");
            break;

    }
if(headX <0|| headX>len||headY<0||headY>wid){
        gameOver=1;
    }
for(i=0;i<countTail;i++){
    if(i==tailX[i]&& i==tailY[i]){
        gameOver=1;
    }
}
if(headX==fruitX&& headY==fruitY)
{
do{
   fruitX=rand()%20;
   fruitY=rand()%20;
}while(fruitX==0 ||fruitY==0);
score+=10;
countTail++;

}
}

int main(){
    int m,n;
    char c;


    defaultsetting();

    printf("Enter level of game\n");
    scanf("%d",&level);

    while(!gameOver)
    {

        draw();
        userinput();
        logic();
        my_sleep(level);
    }

    printf("Your Score =%d",score);

    return 0;
}
void my_sleep(int level){
    if(level==1){
        sleep(1);
    }
    else if(level==2){
        sleep(0.4);
    }
    else if(level==3){
        sleep(0.02);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, move `srand(time(0));` from `logic()` to `main()` -- you need to initialize the rand number generator just once, not on every step of your algorithm.

Comment: Please show what output you are getting and what output you expect instead.

Comment: `sleep` expects an integer, so `sleep(0.4)` and `sleep(0.02)` do exactly the same thing as `sleep(0)`, i.e. not much.

Comment: I want still border as output but when I increased the length and height of border, border is running in console. Unable to post output here.

Comment: Your description "border is running" is unclear to me. Please show the ouptut you get and the one you expect. Also, please apply indentation to the shown code.

Comment: Please reduce your [mre] to only demonstrate the problems you have with the border. I assume that most of the game is not needed for that.

Comment: "Unable to post output here." Why? What happens if you try? What happens if you try to show a simpler/smaller version, which conveys the difference of output you get and expect. If you really cannot show the output, then you need to do a lot more describing.

Comment: https://github.com/gupta31/SnakeGameInC/blob/main/snakegame_undesiredoutput.PNG     you can go this link and see the output when i increased the length and width of border. "Running" means it keep making border in console due to which i am unable to play the game on console. For playing border should be in "still" position. Hope this one helps you to understand the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/gupta31/SnakeGameInC/blob/main/snakegame_outputwhenlen%26widthis20.PNG   this output is fine when i took len=20,wid=20 but it is not at center and also not covering the whole console screen.I want to make border which covers whole console screen.

Comment: @yunnosch.please look my comments

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output 9 warnings.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall --Wextra -Wconnversion -pedantiic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: the function `kbhit()` not defined in the currently included header files nor is it one of the user defined functions.  Therefore, the code will NOT perform as desired

Comment: the function `getch()` not defined in the currently included header files nor is it one of the user defined functions.  Therefore, the code will NOT perform as desired.

Comment: suggest replacing the function calls to `sleep()` with calls to `nanosleep()`, found in `time.h` then you can enter fractional second times as some number of nanoseconds